# SMTP Mail From - Friendly Name

Tags: email, smtp

From one of our application we are sending an email to an SMTP relay with the MAIL FROM set as "Mr Smith " (without the quotes).

This is working in our Live environment but in our test environment it keeps failing with the message "555 5.5.4 Unsupported option: Smith".

I have figured out that it is because there is a space between Mr Smith, and that if it was all one word it would work fine.

Does anyone know what the formatting standards are for the MAIL FROM option? Does it need to have quotes around the name, ie "Mr Smith" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitive guide to SMTP is [RFC 5321](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5321), "Simple Mail Transport Protocol".

According to paragraph 3.3, the first (or only) argument to the `MAIL FROM`command is `<reverse-path>`, and the `<reverse-path>` portion of same first-or-only argument is expected to contain the **source mailbox *between `<` and `>` brackets***.

In paragraph 4.1.1.2, is states that the "*reverse-path consists of the sender mailbox*". Further reading indicates that under some circumstances it is appropriate for the reverse path to be null, in which case it appears as `<>`.

The requirement for the reverse path to be enclosed in brackets has essentially always been present, going as far back as the original publication of [RFC 772](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc772) thirty four years ago.

The reason you're getting an "Unsupported option" error message is that if the reverse path is followed by a space and then more data, that additional data is defined to be parameters to negotiated service extensions.

Comment: I've been going through the Java code and adding tonnes of debugging entries.  The MimeMessage setFrom is 'new InternetAddress("mr@smith.com", "Mr Smith")' and I have written the exact message being passed through to the SMTP server.  This shows the From as 'Mr Smith <mr@smith.com>' and following it is the Recipient details.

Comment: Ah! Well, now that you've identified a specific framework, I can tell you that it looks like you should be using `SMTPMessage`, not `MimeMessage`. The `SMTPMessage` class has several additional methods that are useful to an email sender, including a `setEnvelopeFrom()` method that will allow you to specify a valid envelope sender.

Comment: I was being stupid.  There was another part of the code (it wasn't written by me) which was defining the FROM email address as well (don't ask me why there were two) and not putting " " around the name and as a result it was doing Mr Smith <mr@smith.com>.